# How to add text in \1 level around \2 in outline package

Tags: itemize

I want something like:

```
1. foo
   foo foo
   a. bar
   b. bar
   foo foo
2. foo
```

My current code is like:

```
\begin{outline}[enumerate]

\1 title

foo1

    \2 foo

    \2 foo

    \2 foo

foo2

    \2 bar
 
    \2 bar
foo3
```

... and `foo2` & `foo3` will not come back to `\1` from `\2`. Is there any way to do this?